# Virtual Trading Platform with Django Rest Framework (Good Idea)?

Tags: django, stack

Trading application relies on many requests is it advisable to build the API backend with Django rest framework with scalability in mind? Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Use graphql. It is a very powerful API system. For Django there is this library called Graphene-django. Here is the link  https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/